# Can't navigate to next scene through function

Tags: react-native

I am using the React Native Router and onPress I want to use a function which works like I want but I can't use the navigate function inside it

This works:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={Actions.home} underlayColor="transparent">
</TouchableHighlight>
```

But this doesn't:

```
nextScene = () => {
      if(this.state.tekstNummer >= Object.keys(teksten).length-1){
        Actions.home
      }
      else{
        this.setState({tekstNummer: this.state.tekstNummer+1})
      }
    };

<TouchableHighlight onPress={nextScene} underlayColor="transparent">
</TouchableHighlight>
```

The else statement works but the Action.home inside the if statement doesn't work. How could I fix this and for what reason doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually calling your home function.

```
nextScene = () => {
      if(this.state.tekstNummer >= Object.keys(teksten).length-1){
        // call the function()
        Actions.home();
      }
      else{
        this.setState({tekstNummer: this.state.tekstNummer+1})
      }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't think it would be this simple but how come I don't have to use the parenthesis outside of the function?

Comment: Because you attach the function to the onPress property. The TouchableHighlight will call the passed-in function when the press actually occurs. In other words: you pass a reference to the function to TouchableOpacity, only when the button is pressed the function will be executed